# IE8 will not display frames when http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" is used

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, radix, x-ua-compatible

I have the following html code that works without the http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" in IE8 but fails when it has it. I think the order is correct (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/07/18/optimal-html-head-ordering-to-avoid-parser-restarts-redownloads-and-improve-performance.aspx), and the code is valid so I don't see the reason why it would do this.

Please, any explanation?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8, IE=edge" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<base href="file:///D:/LocalPath/ToFrameElements/">
<title>IE8 stuff</title>
</head>
```

Comment: base href is a local path?

Comment: yes it is... but works on higher ie versions. The path is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frames wouldn't appear because of the standard document mode that the

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8, IE=edge" />
```

or not relaying on the browser's error tolerance, the syntactically correct way

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8; IE=edge" />
```

implies.

This is because in the standard document rendering mode IE does not allow the use of base href with links to the filesystem for security's sake. To have the base href working it can only be achieved by removing the the meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" so that page will run in quirks rendering mode.

Answer (score 0):

Your `X-UA-Compatible` http-equiv string is invalid.

It has 2 values:

1. IE=8 ( IE 8 standards rendering mode )
2. IE=edge ( latest engine )

However, the syntax is incorrect. The correct syntax is:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8; IE=edge" />
```

When multiple values are specified, highest value will be used. That is,

- In IE9 , the page will be rendered in IE 9 standards rendering mode.
- In IE8 , the page will be rendered in IE 8 standards rendering mode.

**Solution: Fix the syntax and retry.**

Reference:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Persona/Browser_compatibility
2. [Define Document Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
3. [Understanding Compatibility Modes in IE8](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx?Redirected=true)

*Sidenote:* IE supports this meta tag starting from IE 8.

Comment: I was wrong, I replaced it with <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content=" IE=8; IE=edge" />, notice the misstyped space. Because of that it didn't read the document as IE8 and did load correctly and I accepted your answer so. So now I tried with the correct syntax but <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8; IE=edge" /> does not work...

Comment: you should change your base path first. Note the `document.domain` for same origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

The [`base` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE) is defined so that its value must be an absolute URL. Besides, any effect of a `file:` URL is by definition system-dependent. So you should organize your local files and references to them so that a `base` tag is not needed.

Comment: The situation is not that simple and requires the use of base for defining where the elements reside. file:///D:/LocalPath/ToFrameElements/ is an absolute path.